# Max DateTime in a list

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How do you get the max datetime from a list of DateTime values using C# 2.0?

Comment: need ... more ... info ...
Getting the max datetime in a loop , wtf ?
maximum datetime of what ?  what does that loop do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple loop to do this:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue };

DateTime max = DateTime.MinValue; // Start with the lowest value possible...
foreach(DateTime date in dates)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(date, max) == 1)
        max = date;
}

// max is maximum time in list, or DateTime.MinValue if dates.Count == 0;
```

Answer (score 27):

What's with all the iterating....this is very trivial

```
// Given...
List<DateTime> dates = { a list of some dates... }

// This is the max...
DateTime MaxDate = dates.Max();
```

Comment: thanks for adding the newer info... this is what I was looking for

Comment: Also behind the scenes this is still iterating.

Comment: @Jlalonde true but this keeps your code clean and easier to maintain

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean max datetime in *set, collection, or List*?  If so:

```
DateTime max = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (DateTime item in DateTimeList)
{
    if (item > max) max = item;
}
return max;
```

If you mean you want to know the highest possible supported value for any datetime, it's just:

```
DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

var max = new[] { datetime1, datetime2 }.Max();